# multiple roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

We have a polynomial $p(x)=x^5 -ax^3+b$. We need to find the relationship between $a$ and $b$ such that $p(x)$ has multiple roots.

Assume that $p(x)$ has 2 roots $c$ and $d$ with multiplicities $2$ and $3$ respectively. Then 
1) $3c+2d=0$
2) $3c^2+6cd+d^2=-a$
3) $(c^3)*(d^2)= -b$

Thus, $a=3.75c^2$  and $b=-2.25c^5$. and we can find the relationship between $a$ and $b$ then.

Is it the right approach?

Comment: $p$ has multiple (complex) roots iff $\gcd(p,p')\ne1$.

Comment: Note that if "$p(x)$ has 2 roots $c$ and $d$ with multiplicities $2$ and $3$ respectively," then the sum of roots is $2c+3d$, not $3c+2d$.  Are you assuming *only* multiple roots? I read the Question as asking for at least one multiple root.

Answer (score 4):

There is an algorithm which allows you to find if polynomials $f$, $g$ have a common root. You have to calculate [the resultant](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/2WF02/resultant.pdf) of $f$ and $g$, $R(f,g)$.  If it's $0$, then there are common roots. Now polynomial $f$ has multiple roots iff $f$ and $f'$ has common root.

Comment: For univariate (one-variable) polynomials, it's likely efficient just to compute the GCD of $f,g$, which is nontrivial if and only if $f,g$ have a common root.

Comment: @hardmath Ofc you are right but i think it can lead to more complicated computations.

Comment: Can the resultant of $p,p'$ in this particular case be found more easily than $\gcd(p,p')$? The determinant of the [Sylvester matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) gives the resultant, but this is a $9\times 9$ matrix determinant here.

Comment: I dont think its worth arguing but in this case in any row there will be only 3 or 2 nonzero elements and Laplace formula gives almost trivial computation. I guess this is more matter of taste in this case tho.

Comment: @hardmath can I use the Euclidian algorithm and after coming to the stage when just a constant (consisting of a and b) is equal to 0? thus, I secure that a and b have GCD which is not 0?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't trying to be argumentative, just trying to compare.  It seems to me the special structure of coefficients might help to do both approaches.

Comment: @Nika: Yes, the condition for $p,p'$ to have nontrivial GCD would be setting that expression in $a,b$ to zero.

Answer (score 2):

It is not so hard to show that if a polynomial $f$ has $\alpha$ as a root with multiplicity $k$ then $f'$ has $\alpha$ as a root with multiplicity $k-1$. Since $f'(x)=x^2(5x^2-3a)$ you can easily find the root with multiplicity $3$. From this you will be able to find the conditions on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I doubt the “iff”: $f(x)=x^3-1$.

Comment: The “iff“ I your unedited answer.